# Unable to decode stream java.io.FileNotFoundException in android?

Tags: java, android, filenotfoundexception, bitmapfactory

I am new to android and I am getting this error when I try to use `decodefile()`.

Here is the code

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

 if ((requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY ) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK) &&       (data != null)){
         selectedImageUri = data.getData( );
         Log.e("Path1", ""+selectedImageUri);
         path1 = selectedImageUri.getPath();
         file = new File(path1);
         path =file.getAbsolutePath();
         Log.e("Path2", file.getAbsolutePath());

         mImageView.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
    }}

protected void badButtonPressed() {
    final long startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();


    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    // Part 1: Decode image
   >> Bitmap unscaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
     imageHeight = options.outHeight;
     imageWidth = options.outWidth;
    Log.e("w", ""+imageWidth);
    Log.e("h", ""+imageHeight);
```

Please tell me my mistake.

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have edited your post to fix a few English issues. I also bolded the function name using two asterisks.

I can not see the error that you mention.  Please edit your post and show us the error (use > at the start of the line for marking it).

Comment: @RohutGupta You have bolded the function name why? When code formatting already exists?

Comment: which android version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found this answer

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_IMAGE);

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE) {
                try {
                    selectedImagePath = getAbsolutePath(intent.getData());
                    mImageCaptureUri = intent.getData();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public String getAbsolutePath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index =    cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try it.

```
int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 3;
String path;
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY 
            && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        try {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            path = cursor.getString(columnIndex);



            cursor.close();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {

        }

    }
}

public void pickFromGallery()
{
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
             android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i, PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
}
```

Comment: still null pointer error there is nothing is nothing in "path"

Comment: When you call badButtonPressed()?

Comment: I am able to display the image from gallery but when i am trying to perform scaling on that image at that time it gives me this error

Comment: Please write to manifest.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: BitmapFactory(1682): Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException ................... When i call badButtonPressed()

Comment: @Himankshah What do you mean '*still* null pointer error' when your question is about a `FileNotFoundException`?